# Jordan theorem : the boundary statement

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

The Jordan theorem states that if $\Gamma$ is a closed Jordan  curve in $C$, then the complement $C\setminus \Gamma$

1. has two connected components
2. one is bounded, the other is unbounded
3. the boundaries of these two components is $\Gamma$.

[I found a proof](https://minerve.ens-rennes.fr/images/Le_Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Jordan_S.Quayle_V.Le_Gruiec..pdf) of points 1 and 2.

Now I'm searching for point 3.

The two connected components of $C\setminus \Gamma$ are open, so that their boundaries are contained in $\Gamma$.

QUESTION : how to prove the reverse inclusion ? I want to prove that if $A$ is one of the two connected components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Gamma$, then every point of $\Gamma$ is in the boundary of $A$.

Comment: There is no purpose to the close vote currently placed. The context is clearly stated as a trial to prove the Jordan theorem. +1 for your great question.